# Serialization: Escape Input String

Tags: c++, iterator, unicode

In Json strings characters can be escaped with `\\`.
Here is an iterator that can read such strings and convert the escaped characters to UTF-8

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_SERIALIZATION_UNICODE_ITERATOR_H
#define THORSANVIL_SERIALIZATION_UNICODE_ITERATOR_H

#include <iterator>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Serialization
    {

        namespace
        {

long convertHexToDec(char x)
{
    if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')
    {
        return (x - '0');
    }
    else if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'F')
    {
        return 10 + (x - 'A');
    }
    else if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'f')
    {
        return 10 + (x - 'a');
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialization::UnicodeIterator: Invalid Hex Digit in unicode string");
}
        }

template<typename C>
struct UnicodePushBackIterator: std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, char, ptrdiff_t, char*,char&>
{
    C&       cont;
    bool     lastWasSlash;
    int      unicodeCount;
    uint32_t unicodeValue;
    UnicodePushBackIterator(C& c)
        : cont(c)
        , lastWasSlash(false)
        , unicodeCount(0)
    {}
    UnicodePushBackIterator& operator++()       {return *this;}
    UnicodePushBackIterator& operator*()        {return *this;}
    void operator=(char x)
    {
        if (unicodeCount)
        {
            if (unicodeCount == 6)
            {
                if (x != '\\')
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialization::UnicodeIterator: Push->Surrogate pair(No Slash): \\uD8xx Must be followed by \\uDCxx");
                }
                --unicodeCount;
            }
            else if (unicodeCount == 5)
            {
                if (x != 'u')
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialization::UnicodeIterator: Push->Surrogate pair(No u): \\uD8xx Must be followed by \\uDCxx");
                }
                --unicodeCount;
            }
            else
            {
                unicodeValue <<= 4;
                unicodeValue += convertHexToDec(x);
                --unicodeCount;
                if (unicodeCount == 0)
                {
                    if (unicodeValue <= 0x7F)
                    {
                        // Encode as single UTF-8 character
                        cont.push_back(unicodeValue);
                    }
                    else if (unicodeValue <= 0x7FF)
                    {
                        // Encode as two UTF-8 characters
                        cont.push_back(0xC0 |((unicodeValue >>  6)));
                        cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  0) & 0x3F));
                    }
                    else if (unicodeValue <= 0xFFFF)
                    {
                        if ((unicodeValue & 0xFC00) != 0xD800)
                        {
                            // Encode as three UTF-8 characters
                            cont.push_back(0xE0 |((unicodeValue >> 12)));
                            cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  6) & 0x3F));
                            cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  0) & 0x3F));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // We have a found first part of surrogate pair
                            unicodeCount    = 6;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Surrogate pair
                        if ((unicodeValue & 0xFC00FC00) != 0xD800DC00)
                        {
                            throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialization::UnicodeIterator: Push->Surrogate pair(No DC): \\uD8xx Must be followed by \\uDCxx");
                        }

                        // Decode surrogate pair
                        unicodeValue    = 0x00010000 | ((unicodeValue & 0x03FF0000) >> 6) | (unicodeValue & 0x000003FF);

                        // Encode as 4 UTF-8 characters
                        cont.push_back(0xF0 |((unicodeValue >> 18)));
                        cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >> 12) & 0x3F));
                        cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  6) & 0x3F));
                        cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  0) & 0x3F));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       else if (lastWasSlash)
        {
            switch(x)
            {
                case '"':   cont.push_back('"');    break;
                case '\\':  cont.push_back('\\');   break;
                case '/':   cont.push_back('/');    break;
                case 'b':   cont.push_back('\b');   break;
                case 'f':   cont.push_back('\f');   break;
                case 'n':   cont.push_back('\n');   break;
                case 'r':   cont.push_back('\r');   break;
                case 't':   cont.push_back('\t');   break;
                case 'u':   unicodeCount = 4; unicodeValue = 0; break;
            }
            lastWasSlash    = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (x == '\\')
            {
                lastWasSlash    = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cont.push_back(x);
            }
        }
    }
};

template<typename I>
struct UnicodeWrapperIterator: std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char, ptrdiff_t, char*,char&>
{
    I                   iter;
    std::vector<char>   cont;
    std::size_t         index;
    UnicodeWrapperIterator(I iter)
        : iter(iter)
        , index(0)
    {}
    bool operator==(UnicodeWrapperIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return iter == rhs.iter;
    }
    bool operator!=(UnicodeWrapperIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    UnicodeWrapperIterator& operator++()
    {
        ++index;
        if (index == cont.size())
        {
            ++iter;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    char operator*()
    {
        checkBuffer();
        return cont[index];
    }
    private:
    void checkBuffer()
    {
        if (index == cont.size())
        {
            cont.clear();
            index   = 0;

            cont.push_back(*iter);

            if (cont[0] == '\\')
            {
                ++iter;
                char next   = *iter;
                switch(next)
                {
                    case '"':   cont[0] = '"';    break;
                    case '\\':  cont[0] = '\\';   break;
                    case '/':   cont[0] = '/';    break;
                    case 'b':   cont[0] = '\b';   break;
                    case 'f':   cont[0] = '\f';   break;
                    case 'n':   cont[0] = '\n';   break;
                    case 'r':   cont[0] = '\r';   break;
                    case 't':   cont[0] = '\t';   break;
                    case 'u':   decodeUnicode();  break;
                    default:    cont[0] = next;   break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void decodeUnicode()
    {
        cont.clear();
        long    unicodeValue    = getUnicodeHex();

        if (unicodeValue <= 0x7F)
        {
            // Encode as single UTF-8 character
            cont.push_back(unicodeValue);
        }
        else if (unicodeValue <= 0x7FF)
        {
            // Encode as two UTF-8 characters
            cont.push_back(0xC0 |((unicodeValue >>  6)));
            cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  0) & 0x3F));
        }
        else if (unicodeValue <= 0xFFFF)
        {
            if ((unicodeValue & 0xFC00) != 0xD800)
            {
                // Encode as three UTF-8 characters
                cont.push_back(0xE0 |((unicodeValue >> 12)));
                cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  6) & 0x3F));
                cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  0) & 0x3F));
            }
            else
            {
                // We have a found first part of surrogate pair
                decodeSurrogatePairs(unicodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
    void decodeSurrogatePairs(long unicodeValue)
    {
        ++iter;
        char nextChar  = *iter;
        if (nextChar != '\\')
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialization::UnicodeIterator: Iter->Surrogate pair(No Slash): \\uD8xx Must be followed by \\uDCxx");
        }
        ++iter;
        nextChar  = *iter;
        if (nextChar != 'u')
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialization::UnicodeIterator: Iter->Surrogate pair(No u): \\uD8xx Must be followed by \\uDCxx");
        }

        unicodeValue = (unicodeValue << 16) + getUnicodeHex();

        // Surrogate pair
        if ((unicodeValue & 0xFC00FC00) != 0xD800DC00)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialization::UnicodeIterator: Iter->Surrogate pair(No DC): \\uD8xx Must be followed by \\uDCxx");
        }

        // Decode surrogate pair
        unicodeValue    = 0x00010000 | ((unicodeValue & 0x03FF0000) >> 6) | (unicodeValue & 0x000003FF);

        // Encode as 4 UTF-8 characters
        cont.push_back(0xF0 |((unicodeValue >> 18)));
        cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >> 12) & 0x3F));
        cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  6) & 0x3F));
        cont.push_back(0x80 |((unicodeValue >>  0) & 0x3F));
    }
    long getUnicodeHex()
    {
        long unicodeValue   = 0;

        for(int loop=0;loop < 4;++loop)
        {
            ++iter;
            char x = *iter;

            unicodeValue <<= 4;
            unicodeValue    += convertHexToDec(x);
        }
        return unicodeValue;
    }
};

template<typename C> UnicodePushBackIterator<C> make_UnicodePushBackIterator(C& cont)   {return UnicodePushBackIterator<C>(cont);}
template<typename I> UnicodeWrapperIterator<I>  make_UnicodeWrapperIterator(I iter)     {return UnicodeWrapperIterator<I>(iter);}

    }
}

#endif
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    // Note use of C++11 string literal.
    // Don't need to escape slashes in code.
    std::string     input(R"(Input:\tTab\n\\\u0102\n\u011D\n\u013d\n)");

    std::string     output(make_UnicodeWrapperIterator(std::begin(input)),
                           make_UnicodeWrapperIterator(std::end(input)));

    std::string     copied;
    std::copy(std::begin(input), std::end(input),
              make_UnicodePushBackIterator(copied));

    std::cout << "input: " << input  << "\n"
              << "output:" << output << "\n"
              << "copied:" << copied << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newsletter suggested I try to answer this, so here is my attempt:

This looks like a lot of repeated code here.  I don't think this can be shortened really, but I would create a function to do the conversion in:

```cpp
switch(x)
{
    case '"':   cont.push_back('"');    break;
    case '\\':  cont.push_back('\\');   break;
    case '/':   cont.push_back('/');    break;
    case 'b':   cont.push_back('\b');   break;
    case 'f':   cont.push_back('\f');   break;
    case 'n':   cont.push_back('\n');   break;
    case 'r':   cont.push_back('\r');   break;
    case 't':   cont.push_back('\t');   break;
    case 'u':   unicodeCount = 4; unicodeValue = 0; break;
}
```

More like this:

```cpp
char convertChar (char c) {
    switch(x)
    {
        case '"':
        case '\\':
        case '/':
            return x;

        case 'b':   return '\b';
        case 'f':   return '\f';
        case 'n':   return '\n';
        case 'r':   return '\r';
        case 't':   return '\t';
    }
}
```

Then, you can change the switch statement like this:

```cpp
if (x == 'u')
{
    unicodeCount = 4;
    unicodeValue = 0;
}
else
{
    cont.push_back(convertChar(x));
}
```

Further down, you could reuse that again:

```cpp
switch(next)
{
    case '"':
    case '\\':
    case '/':
    case 'b':
    case 'f':
    case 'n':
    case 'r':
    case 't':
        cont[0] = convertChar(next); break;

    case 'u':   decodeUnicode();  break;
    default:    cont[0] = next;   break;
}
```

Otherwise, it looks good to me.